# Pandas dataframes reindex on the union of their respective datetime timestamp indexes

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two dataframes. There are two identical columns in each dataframe. I can plot it fine, with the datetimes shown correctly as the index on the x-axis.

The index `'TimeStamp'` for dfEURUSD is different than the dataframe for dfGBPUSD. I am trying to get them to be the same length and resample the missing data so that the two timeseries are the same length. But I run into trouble:

```
def union(a, b):
    """ return the union of two lists """
    return list(set(a) | set(b))


print(len(dfEURUSD.index))
print(len(dfGBPUSD.index))
newindex = union(dfEURUSD.index, dfGBPUSD.index)
newindex = sorted(set(newindex))
print(len(newindex))

print(newindex)
```

This gives this output

```
151527
113903
264664

[Timestamp('2015-11-12 17:49:15.512000'), Timestamp('2015-11-12 17:49:15.523000'), Timestamp('2015-11-12 17:49:15.540000'), Timestamp('2015-11-12 17:49:15.727000'), Timestamp('2015-11-12 17:49:16.059000'), Timestamp('2015-11-12 17:49:16.301000'), etc...
```

If I try to reindex with

```
dfEURUSD.reindex(newindex, method='ffill')
dfGBPUSD.reindex(newindex, method='ffill')
```

Give the error:

```
File "/home/idf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2133, in reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex a non-unique index "

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think problem is with duplicity in index - you can check it by `newindex.index.get_duplicates()`

Comment: Thanks. That actually helped.